# Is there a way to make the C# compiler issue a warning when instance variable is hidden(shadowed)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings

I am refactoring a little bit of code and I think I have created some instance variables that are being hidden(shadowed) in older methods.  I want to see a warning wherever the hiding(shadowing) happens so I can check to make sure that it's actually what I want (and it's hardly *ever* what I want).  Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: I had never heard the term 'shadowing' before, thanx for posting! http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/variables/60shadow-variables.html

Comment: @tjb Shadowing is the (official) VB term, in C# it is called hiding.

Comment: Will edit to match this convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run Code Analysis, that'll show up (as [CA1500](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182216.aspx) from the [Maintanability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182211.aspx) section).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into any productivity tools such as Resharper?  http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

It will find that (and probably proactively warn you) with very little effort on your part.

Comment: I've heard of ReSharper and even looked into it.  Do you find it really helpful?

Comment: Its amazingly helpful.  Iv'e actually come to depend on it and have purchased my own copy until the dev managers get around to purchasing a site license.  All the other developers on my SCRUM are now jealous of my productivity and some have even asked about purchasing :).

Comment: I use resharper every single day, if i ever code in visual studio without resharper built into it, i feel that i might as well be coding in notepad++.

Comment: I'm a R# user as well, and can't recommend it highly enough.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to make the C# compiler emit this warning.